# Is $\Bbb Z_2$ free?

Tags: projective-module, free-modules

As a counter example for a projective module which is not free my instructor gave this one:

$\Bbb Z_6=\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_3$

$\Bbb Z_6$ projective, so $\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$ are projective but $\Bbb Z_2$ is not free.

But he also gave

Any ring with unity as an example of a free module. I know $\Bbb Z_2$ is a ring with unity, So shouldn't it be free.

Comment: You need to always specify free or projective *as a module over some specified ring*.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The ring is $\Bbb Z_6$.

Comment: In that case $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is not free. The example given to you says that any ring is free as a module over itself, not necessarily over some other ring.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Why it is not free over $\Bbb Z_6$ but free over itself?

Comment: Look at the definition of being free and note that clearly a basis would need to consist of a single element.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: The definition I am using says: $F$ is free if it has a non empty basis. I still didn't get you.

Comment: Please try to write up what it would mean for something to be a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a module over $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40596/discussion-between-marana-and-tobias-kildetoft).

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf Z_6$ is a free $\mathbf Z_6$-module, and the *Chinese remainder theorem* says it is isomorphic to $\;\mathbf Z_2\oplus\mathbf Z_3$ (both as $\mathbf Z$-modules  and as $\mathbf Z_6$-modules). Projective modules are direct summands of free modules, hence  $\;\mathbf Z_2\;$ and $\;\mathbf Z_3\;$ are  projective $\mathbf Z_6$-modules.

*Note:*

To remove any ambiguity, none of these $$\mathbf Z$-modules is projective, as they have torsion.